# How to integrate apache solr in apache tomcat 7?

Tags: solr, tomcat7

Is there any way to integrate apache solr in tomcat 7 or do I have to run two servers in my application? Can in run apache solr within tomcat and not as a separate server?

Comment: One great way to do it is with Spring Data Solr: http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-solr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official answer is: Run it as a stand alone application.

> **No Longer Supported**
>
> Beginning with Solr 5.0, Support for deploying Solr as a WAR in servlet containers like Tomcat is no longer supported.
>
> For information on how to install Solr as a standalone server, please see [Installing Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr).

Background about the the decision for this move can be found [on the Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar).

> Solr is intended to be a server not a Java web application, similar to mysql or the Apache web server. When Solr was first created, designing it as a web application was a convenient choice, to avoid writing a lot of tricky code to build a network layer. These days, this design decision has become a limiting factor.
>
> When you download Solr and install it onto your machine, it should be Solr that gets started. It should not be necessary to install Solr into a third-party application (servlet container) before it will work.
>
> At this time, Solr is still a webapp, but this is an internal implementation detail, not an immutable property. The intention is to make Solr into a completely standalone application. Startup scripts that start the included container are the first step towards that goal. Jetty might still be the technology used once Solr is a standalone application, but if that happens, it will be internally embedded.

Answer (score 0):

`Solr` is still a web app. They are suggesting that not to use it in another servlet container as its not been recommended and tested by them.

They are giving a fully tested system and don't want others(developers) to invest time in testing it with other containers.

I have used `solr` 3.4 version and deployed it in tomcat server on port 8080. 
My application is deployed in another `tomcat` at 8080 port and is on another machine.

I have created the solr war and deployed the same in tomcat. and only 8080 port of that server is made open and been access by our application only.

I am not sure about the `solr` version 5 ...i.e. whether that can be deployed in other container other than `jetty`...but I think it can be deployed in `tomcat`...you need to try the same...

Other thing is that dont deply application war and `solr` war in the same container or in a single container. The reason is if one of the application goes down everything will be down.

Like if `solr` goes down then the application may go down, which is not a good for the application.

Comment: Solr version 6 is already on the horizon, I would not suggest to build it your own as they say: _Note that if you choose to do this kind of deployment, you are on your own._

Comment: @cheffe: I fully agree with you. I have given my opinion and experience to OP... Now it's totally his own decision how he want to take it further...

Comment: understood, I should make more use of emojis :)